# Style and PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I use PHPMailer to submit automated e-mails. Style I added in the message isn't working at all.

Here's an example:

```
$message .= '<p style="font-family:"Sans Serif";font-size:22px">Merci d’avoir utilisé les services de gestion de projet de, nous apprécions votre confiance. Votre facture est disponible en cliquant sur lien ci-dessous:</p>';
```

`Sans Serif` isn't used, nor is font-size, etc.

Comment: This is most likely a result of the mail client rather than your code. If this is the case then there's not much you can do serverside. How did you determine it "isn't working"?

Comment: You already posted this http://stackoverflow.com/q/38725173/

Comment: I did, but the other post was locked and I couldn't answer - and the post you marked as duplicate wasn't even the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing broken HTML:

```
$message .= '<p style="font-family:"Sans Serif";font-size:22px">[..snip...]
                      ^--start attribute
                                   ^---end attribute
```

So `Sans` is seen as some new/unknown HTML attribute, **NOT** as the name of a font.

Something more like this would work:

```
$message .= '<p style="font-family:\'Sans Serif\';font-size:22px">
```

Note the `\'`.

Comment: It's a repost http://stackoverflow.com/q/38725173/ with the same error.

Comment: That fully works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take `Sans Serif` out of the double quotes.